# If else statment with tab i'm on now Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

Hello everybody I'm working on Jquery tabs, I have a tab which is a class function addClass and remove content

I have an IF ELSE made ​​and looks like

```
$ (function () {
  if (ui.panel.id == 'tab-1') {
    $ ("#DIV_ID").addClass ("CLASS", 0);
    return false;
  } else {
    $ ("#DIV_ID").removeClass ("CLASS", 0);
    return false;
  }
});
```

Is this a way to look on with tab he is? If not how should I do?

[EDIT]

Mine code http://jsfiddle.net/Csq6x/12/

Comment: Well, does the code you show work or not?

Comment: You have spaces invading your code. This does not look like jQuery to me.

Comment: yeah the tabs is working fine, but it aint add or remove the classes

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is case-sensitive, so `AddClass` and `addClass` are different things. Although excess whitespace is ignored, it's not allowed to put them in identifiers. Also, the `addClass` and `removeClass` methods accept only one argument. Furthermore, `# DIV_ID` would probably not work because it would match an empty ID (which would not be possible) with a descendant node having tagname "DIV_ID". You need to change that to `#DIV_ID`:

```
$ (function () {
  if (ui.panel.id == 'tab-1') {
    $ ("#DIV_ID"). addClass ("CLASS");
    return false;
  } else {
    $ ("#DIV_ID"). removeClass ("CLASS");
    return false;
  }
});
```

Also, I don't know where you've put this snippet, but note that this code is executed once the document is ready. So if it's within `<script>` tags, it's executed and not when switching tabs.

Comment: for some reason there were some whitespaces in mine Question, edited it, but its the same as yourse now? or do i miss something?

Comment: "Also, I don't know where you've put this snippet, but note that this code is executed once the document is ready. So if it's within <script> tags, it's executed and not when switching tabs." it is within the <script> but i want it to executed when ether im switching.. What i need to chance to make it executed when youre switching?

Comment: I've added an update for the ID before you've posted your comment. What is the ID of the button / tab used for switching? Where should `CLASS` be constructed from?

Comment: You've not included the library that provides the `.tabs` method.

Comment: it is in the jquery-ui.min.js? else mine tabs woudnt work either?

Comment: It isn't. Open your error console and reload the jsfiddle, you'll see an error on it.

Comment: yeah, is see.. but i dont got that error when im on mine live version

Comment: If you want help, you really need to provide more information. Look into the documentation of your tabs plugin.

Comment: is there anyway we can contact? other then this comments? since i cant come into the chat (repuation)